# how to send data to multiple activities using putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), DetailView.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", Integer.toString(position + 1)); 
                startActivity(intent);
```

Here as you can see I am sending the value of position to a class named DetailView using putExtra. I want to send the same position to another class, I don't want to launch the activity, I want to just send the value of "position". Can any one of you please let me know how can that be done. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance. Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: I suggest you to use SharedPreference, with this you can access values from it anywhere in the app

Comment: The value of position is not same always, it keeps changing every time. Can that be done using shared preferences? Every time i need to store value in shared preference right?

Comment: you can update the sharedpreference, and that updated value will be available in your app anywhere

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Will give a try to this.

Comment: You have accepted a rather poor answer which will not provide update notification but rather require your receivers to poll for changes, please reconsider, as a broadcast intent is most likely the best fit for your needs.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)

Comment: @ChrisStratton I do not have much knowledge about broadcast receivers, will learn about that and will try to implement Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to launch other activity there are three options that i can provide you.

**1.** Create `public static int position` and access it view `class` name.

*When `setting` value `ClassName.position=value here..`*

*When `gettting` from any `class` used as `ClassName.position;`*

**2.** Create a `class` with `setter` and `getter` method.

**3.** Store value in `sharedPrefrence`

Update each above when your `position` value change.

Comment: In the first one access it view class name, I did not understand that? sorry.

Comment: Storing in shared preferences worked. 1 didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for updating me about this also for accepting my answer.

Comment: No.  Neither the first nor third of these mechanisms provide update notification, while the second is difficult as there may be no instance of the target class to inform, and you cannot simply go and make one in the usual singleton pattern.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i think you should provide your answer, if you not agree with others.These are the way we do as per the question required.Your answer may help to get more knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Where else will this class that you need to pass the position variable be used?

If you are already creating a new instance of the class the best way might be to simply pass the value through a constructor.

Otherwise I would recommend adding either a `public` or `public static` method to the class that you want to receive the position variable.

```
public class PositionReceiver {
    private int mPosition; 

    public void setPosition(int position){
        mPosition = position;
    }

}
```

or

```
public class PositionReceiver {
    private static int sPosition; 

    public static setPosition(int position){
        sPosition = position;
    }

}
```

Comment: No.  You must never call the constructor of an Android Activity subclass, as the result will be non-functional.  Only the system may create *working* instances of activities.  Calling a public method is not necessarily non-functional, but a bit risky/tricky as you don't necessarily have any instance to act on that information.